# Logstash character encoding with cisco syslog

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have set up a ELK stack on a server. I configured logstash and and the other things and send syslog test messages to logstash. Everything works fine.

Now i try to send syslog messages from a Cisco WLC and Cisco Switch to logstash and it seems that the message encoding is wrong.

In the logstash logfile i see the following entry (i removed the message)

***[2018-01-09T16:04:24,603][WARN ][logstash.codecs.plain    ] Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured. {:text=>"0\x82\u0002B\u0002\u0001\u0001\u000...[REMOVED BECAUSE OF SECURITY PURPOSES], :expected_charset=>"UTF-8"}***

The input of my logstash config file is the following:

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 514
    type => syslog
    codec => plain {
     charset => "ISO-8859-1"
    }
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
     add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
     add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}


output {
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
}
```

I already tried to experiment with the codec in the input but with no success. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash only supports RFC3164 syslog messages, and Cisco only supports RFC5424.
so you need to find a way to convert RFC5424 to RFC3164

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I had a default "tcp" mode in input config. I replaced it for "beats" (because I use filebeat to send the logs to logstash), and the issue was solved.